# Qt GroupBox Change Item Width With The Window

Tags: c++, qt, resize, groupbox

I have a GroupBox Which is inside a gridLayout. In the groupBox I have a QLineEdit Which I want to change width when the windows width is changed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a vertical or horizontal layout into the Groupbox, this will let QLineEdit to get resized together with groupbox and main window.